# Android: Modify xml from resource and asset

Tags: android, xml, assets

As I read from several website, editing xml stored inside res/ folder **not possible**

But I really need to modify the xml inside res/ folder, for example I have myxml.xml inside res/xml/

If editing it not possible, so is there any way to modify it?

Is that possible doing this:

1. **Delete** res/xml/myxml.xml then **Copy** a new one from asset folder?
2. **Rename** res/xml/myxml.xml to myxml.xml.old then **Make** a new one?

How about edit xml file inside assets folder? Is that possible?

**Logic :**

There's an app that reads myxml.xml from res/xml/ instead of having 2 different apk with different preferences. I just want to merge them to one and make an option, when the option is save off course it will need to modify myxml.xml inside res/xml/

**Details**

Actually some preference saved inside myxml.xml, the preference is

```
<iconmask img1="iconmask" />

<scale factor="0.75" />
```

I just trying to edit iconmask and scale factor value

Comment: Perhaps if you explained why you think you need to do this, someone could offer up an alternative solution. But the short answer is no, you can't.

Comment: At run-time or while writing the app?

Comment: Editing xml files in your res/ folder is definitely possible while writing the app, as that's where you keep your layouts, strings.xml, etc.  
If you want to do this at runtime, that's another problem, but I'm not sure why you would **need** to do that.

Comment: I need to doing that at runtime, I know that's not possible, just asking is there any alternative

Comment: Once again is this xml and the preferences in an app different from the one you are trying to develop?

Comment: This is my preferences from my app that can be used from app that another people develop

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to edit neither in the `res` nor in the `assets` folder. This will be really hard work to do and probably will not work on all devices systems as I imagine you would need to change file permissions and operate with file system commands directly.

**Additionally these changes would be overriden once you decide to update your app!!**

I rather advise you to change your logic - on app install copy the default xml in the internal app storage. Use this xml from then on. There you can modify whenever you like. Also refering to files located there is also very easy.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but shortly, there's an app that reads myxml.xml from res/xml/ instead of having 2 different apk with different preferences. I just want to merge them to one and make an option, when the option is save off course it will need to modify myxml.xml inside res/xml/

Comment: @ do you have control over this app? If you have the codes is far easier to change the app to read inner storage xml rather than change res file. You can also ship both res files and have the switch of preference just change the name of the file used

Comment: I know that, but sadly I don't have control over this app

Comment: So question is to inluence resources of another app. I find this kind of undesired behavior

Comment: It's not like that way, as I said it's hard to explain. Like GO Launcher Ex (on Play Store), read myxml.xml from res/xml/ from their themes. "Their Themes" that I want to make ...

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: Take a look above, I have added more details